# jQuery Mobile + requirejs: pagebeforecreate event randomly firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, requirejs

I need some help!

I'm coding a debug library that will inject a button in every jQuery Mobile page header. I'm using one HTML file, multiple jQuery Mobile pages inside, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TuBa GameS</title>   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- CSS stylesheets -->
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <!-- jQuery Mobile CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquerymobile/jquerymobile.css" />

    <!-- RequireJS, load main script -->
    <script data-main="js/app/index.js" src="js/require.js"></script>

  </head>

<body>
<!-- ================== [ Page: #splash ] ================== -->
  <div data-role="page" id="splash">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h2>TuBa GameS</h2>
   </div>
   <div data-role="content">
     <ul data-role="listview">
         <li><a href="#userpass">TEST Page in DOM: #userpass</a></li>   
     </ul> 
   </div> <!-- END: content -->
 </div> <!-- END: page #splash -->

<!-- ================== [ Page: #userpass ] ================== -->

    <div data-role="page" id="userpass">
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h2>TuBa GameS</h2>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page: index.html#userpass</p>
      </div> <!-- END: content -->
    </div> <!-- END: page #userpass -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using requirejs, and writing the "header button inject" code in jQuery Mobile's "pagebeforecreate", so I add the button BEFORE ENHACEMENT IN EVERY data-role="page"

The problem is that the "pagebeforecreate" event is randomly firing: sometimes it doesn't fire at all, sometimes it's fired for only the "visible" page, sometimes for two pages... I supposse that is a problem related with requirejs and dependencies order.

This is the code of the debug requirejs module:

```
define ( ['jquery', 'jquerymobile'], // Modules required

function ($) {

/* We add the debug button to header (left side) of every JQM page
 * BEFORE being enhaced
 */
console.log("Number of JQM pages in DOM: " + $("[data-role='page']").length);

$("[data-role='page']").each ( function (index) { 

    $(this).on( "pagebeforecreate", function( event, ui ) {

        var pageid = $(this).attr("id");

        console.log("JQM page id=[" + pageid + "] is going to be enhaced!");

    }); // END: pagebeforecreate event

}); // END: JQMpages.each

}); // END: requireJS module
```

Sorry about my poor english, I'm spanish and I'm afraid that my english is not very good. I hope you can help me with this problem. Thanks in advance, guys! You are really awesome!

Comment: You have to delegate event, `$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", ".selector", function)`.

Comment: Thanks, Omar, but it's still not working even if I delegate "pagebeforecreate" event: sometimes the event fires... sometimes not firing.

I used: $(document).on( "pagebeforecreate", "[data-role='page']", function( event, ui ) { ...my code... });

Anyone else can help us with this annoying problem??

Comment: I know RequireJS very well but I don't use jQuery Mobile. Is it possible that the `pagebeforecreate` event happens before the `each` loop executes?

Comment: With the Omar proposal I DON'T USE .each... I directly delegate the "pagebeforecreate" event to all the HTML elements with data-role="page": $(document).on( "pagebeforecreate", "[data-role='page']", function( event, ui ) { ...my code... }); No loop!

Comment: Let me amend my question then: is it possible that the `pagebeforecreate` event happens before `$(document).on(...)` is executed?

Comment: Louis: sure, the event is firing BEFORE $(document).on(...) but... how can I attach code to this event BEFORE firing for first time in a collection of JQM pages?? that's my question!!

Comment: put it in pagebeforeshow instead